# Symfony2 Unrecognized options "simple_form" under "security.firewalls.main"

Tags: php, symfony

I am following this tutorial [Custom Password Authenticator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_password_authenticator.html) and get the following error when I try to implement the simple form:

```
InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized options "simple_form" under "security.firewalls.main"
```

This is my security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        GigCapitol/MasterBundle/Entity/User: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_USER:        ROLE_USER
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_ADMIN
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
            users:
                entity: { class: GigCapitolMasterBundle:User, property: username }

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous:  ~
            provider: users
            simple-form:
                authenticator: MasterAuthenticator
                login_path: master_index
                check_path: master_login_check


    access_control:
        - { path: /, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
        #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
```

What seems to be the issue here?

Comment: As far as I know dashes/hyphens get normalized to underscores so simple-form will end up as simple_form but then it's not set.

Comment: simple_form is added to version 2.4 up.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_password_authenticator.html

Comment: how could this be solved with 2.3 or lower? I'm working on custom Ldap auth and I'm stopped in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the correct key is "simple_form", and you have "simple-form".

Comment: InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized options "simple_form" under "security.firewalls.main"

Answer (score 0):

It seems i had version 2.0 or so, simple_form was implemented in 2.2

Comment: It was implemented in 2.4